# java no such instance method 'org.json.simple.JSONObejct.getJSONArray'

Tags: java, json, java-8

What can be the reason to the error in the title?

I import classes from here:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

And then add watch to the following expression:

```
(((JSONObject)obj).getJSONArray("userTests")
```

And then get:

> java no such instance method 'org.json.simple.JSONObejct.getJSONArray'

Also when run the code, not by watch expession, I get:

> cannot resolve method 'getJSONArray(java.lang.string)'

Comment: I think you are mixing libraries (calling methods of one, but using the other): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941743/org-json-simple-jsonobject-vs-org-json-jsonobject-jsonexception-cannot-be-reso

Comment: You should copy the exact error messages, not write something from your memory. Further, this problem description is inconsistent. If the compiler can’t resolve a message, it will tell you already at compile-time, without the need to run the code.